# How to apply strike formatting using EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus, strikethrough

I'm using EPPlus in a web application with C#. I need to read an Excel file and check its format, I tried it doing the same as this article ([How do I get partial cell styling in excel using EPpplus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884086/how-do-i-get-partial-cell-styling-in-excel-using-eppplus)), and actually all format properties were ok (bold, italic, color...), but the one that I really need is to check the **strike**
text property and it is always set to **false**.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Might want to post your code.  How are you determining what the strike setting is?  It works find for me using cell.Style.Font.Strike.

Comment: Thanks @Ernie, that is exactly what I needed, the problem was that I was using a loop (foreach(var part in cell.RichText)) and that was not working!

Comment: @JohnSaunders! And the answer?

Comment: @joalcego: They like to keep things pretty clean on stack overflow which is why John edited your post.  Its not uncommon and just takes some getting use to. Its also custom to mark the answer that solves your question as the correct one using the checkmark next to it.  And welcome to SO - its a fantastic resource.

Comment: @Ernie Thanks for the help, yes SO is amazing for us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer just so the question doesnt hang out there:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Strike_Format_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517646/how-to-apply-strike-formatting-using-epplus

    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\StrikeFormat.xlsx");
    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var wb = pck.Workbook;
        var ws = wb.Worksheets.First();

        var cell = ws.Cells["A1"];
        Console.WriteLine(cell.Style.Font.Strike);
    }
}
```